# How to connect mysql in a rails application with docker?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker

I created a rails app use mysql database.
Now want to put them into docker container.
I am using docker, docker-machine, docker-compose.

My docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <%= ENV['MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'] %>
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"

web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

My config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
```

When boot app

```
$ docker-compose up
...
sidekiq_1 | Host '172.17.0.5' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
...
```

My web env

```
$ docker-compose run web env
...
DB_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.3:3306
DB_PORT_3306_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.3:3306
DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3
DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306
DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PROTO=tcp
WEB_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.6:3000
WEB_PORT_3000_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.6:3000
WEB_PORT_3000_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.6
WEB_PORT_3000_TCP_PORT=3000
WEB_PORT_3000_TCP_PROTO=tcp
...
```

My docker-machine ip

```
$ docker-machine ip myapp
192.168.99.100
```

Access from browser: `http://192.168.99.100:3000`, then saw error:

```
Mysql2::Error
Host '172.17.0.6' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

`172.17.0.3`, `172.17.0.5`, `172.17.0.6`, etc. Why they use different ips?
Then how to connect mysql? I can't understand the `host` and `port` written in the `config/database.yml` file.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I'm running Rails in host, and MySQL in docker, the official image.

Adding `host: 127.0.0.1` solved the problem.

**config/database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the container name (`db`) to the host, Example:

**config/database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: db
development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
```

Look at you this example: [docker-to-rails-with-rbenv](https://github.com/kalelc/docker-to-rails-with-rbenv)

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer??? Thank you very much, sir.

Answer (score 0):

IPs are assigned by internal DHCP server. This is why they can changed...

I would recommend reading this post http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/17/docker-rails-docker-compose-together-in-your-development-workflow/ which explains how to configure rails app using host name (and not IPs) to properly connect to a database while using docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach:

by mapping the DB-Port:

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

you are connecting the port 3306 of your host to the same port inside the container.
Therefore, you can connect to the database via the port on your "localhost".

so the database.yml would look like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV['dont use MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
```

You have to keep in mind, that users in the DB are not connected from localhost but from the docker network (default 172.x.x.x) so create your users for all hosts (user@`%`)

And never ever use root as your database user.
If you don't want to set up a user for your Rails as root with SQL commands, you can create one when starting the docker container via environment variables.
See [DockerHub-mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).
You can define these environment variables in your docker-compose.yml or when running `docker compose up`